# Creating menus by the normal user

Tags: android

I have a problem, I need to create menu items but I want the user to be able to do that through a GUI where he/she enters the name of the menu item in an edit text and clicks a button to create it. How do I go about this. I will appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to handle menu on user view ie menu as a button not menu key on emulator or device then you can treat menu as general view. you have to handle onclicklistener. in `onclick()` method create the view that you wan to display to the user.

Donot forget to vote the response if it is helpful for you.

Thanks
Deepak